# Byte array, I need to turn it 90 degrees

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, byte

I come to you with an interesting question. 
I have an `uint8_t` array that looks like this :

```
{B10000000,
 B00000000,
 B10000000,
 B00000000,
 B10000000,
 B00000000,
 B10000000,
 B00000000}
```

I need to make a function that returns Bytes based on the columns. 
For example, for the array above

```
row(0) = B10101010
row(1) = B00000000
etc
```

Here is how i have done it so far

```
  static uint8_t column = B00000001;
  static uint8_t k = 0;

  static uint8_t factor[7];
  static uint8_t rows[7];
  rows[k] = 0;

  for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    factor[i] = led[i] & column;
    factor[i] >>= k;
    factor[i] <<= i;
    rows[k] += factor[i];
  }

  if (k < 7) {
    column = column << 1;
    k = k + 1;
  }
  else {
    column = B00000001;
    k = 0;
  }
}
```

But it is not working well for me. Any ideas?

Edit : My bad. Just edited this :

```
  static uint8_t factor[8];
  static uint8_t rows[8];
```

Now i just need to figure it out how to not mirror it and I'm done.

Comment: I see no `10101010` here ... show us *source code.*

Comment: I recommend searching the internet for "c++ bitmap rotation bits".

Comment: ...and I see no columns.

Comment: Pease post an [MCVE].

Comment: Sorry, don't find it interesting.  Been there, done that.

Comment: If it was an `uint64_t` holding the entire bitboard (and you can easily make that happen), that's a [well known](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Flipping+Mirroring+and+Rotating#Rotationby90degreesClockwise) problem

Comment: You may be able to find examples by searching for "c++ bitmap font rotation", as bitmap fonts use matrices of bits.

Comment: Sorry to pick at nits, but I would expect the result to be `row[0] = B10101010;` and `row[1] = B00000000;`, not the columns.

Comment: Yes you are right, Thomas, my bad

Answer (score 0):

For ease of understanding, let's consider a matrix of bits:

```
0110 0101  
1010 0001  
1100 1100
0101 0101
```

The rotation algorithm for a matrix is the same regardless of its inner type.
In the above matrix, there are 8 columns of bits, 4 rows.

The big difference here is accessing the individual bits.
So what we need is some kind of translation between bit (row,column) to (byte address, bit offset).

We know using integer matrices, that we can squeeze them into a one dimensional array using the formula:

```
[1] linear_offset = row * maximum_columns + column;
```

We would like a similar formula, but for bits and bytes.

Using only one dimension, we can calculate byte and bit offset by:

```
unsigned int byte_offset = column / (BITS_PER_BYTE);
unsigned int bit_offset  = column % (BITS_PER_BYTE);
```

According to equation [1], the linear offset requires the row.  In our case, we need to calculate the number of bytes per row.  The bytes per row depends on the maximum columns per row.  So we have:

```
unsigned int linear_byte_offset = row * ((MAXIMUM_COLUMNS + BITS_PER_BYTE - 1) / BITES_PER_BYTE) + byte_offset;
```

To change a bit:

```
// Clear the bit
byte = byte & (~(1 << bit_offset));
// Then set the bit
byte = byte | (1 << bit_offset);
```

With the above algorithm, we can read any bit position in the matrix and write to any bit position by referring to their row and column ordinates.

This means that any rotation algorithm that uses row and column positioning (ordinates) can be used; such as a rotation algorithm.

The remaining algorithm is left as an exercise for the OP.

*(Note:  A specialized code can be written for the case of 90 degree rotation that may be more efficient than using a generic matrix rotation algorithm).*